# issue with fx scene builder

Tags: java, scenebuilder

Hey I got this error when trying to start my fx application. I'm using icons which I believe are part of an external jar (com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control). So I downloaded the jar and put it in referenced libraries, nothing happened. Then added it as an external annotation to the fx library. Didn't solve the problem. Any idea's?

> > javafx.fxml.LoadException:  /C:/Users/Gebruiker/eclipse-workspace/Pyxus/bin/application/Layout.fxml
>
> at
>   javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2625)
>     at
>   javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(FXMLLoader.java:2863)
>     at
>   javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processImport(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
>     at
>   javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processProcessingInstruction(FXMLLoader.java:2676)
>     at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2542)
>     at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2466)
>     at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2435)    at
>   application.Main.start(Main.java:18)  at
>   javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:919)
>     at
>   javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$11(PlatformImpl.java:449)
>     at
>   javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$9(PlatformImpl.java:418)
>     at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native
>   Method)   at
>   javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:417)
>     at
>   javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
>     at
>   javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native
>   Method)   at
>   javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:175)
>     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.Icon    at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190)
>     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
>     at
>   javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadTypeForPackage(FXMLLoader.java:2931)
>     at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadType(FXMLLoader.java:2920)
>     at
>   javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(FXMLLoader.java:2861)
>     ... 15 more

Comment: Java cannot find the library (`ClassNotFoundException: com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.Icon`). I suggest researching how to properly include external libraries in your application.

Comment: first time using javafx, but ive used ext libraries for over 5 years now so I know how to include that xd I rather think that it has smth to do with putting it into the fx folder

Comment: Except JavaFX libraries are added to the classpath just like any other. If you have done so, then something else is going on and we would likely need to see more of the situation. Please consider adding a [mcve] to demonstrate the problem, per the [ask] article.

Comment: I am not familiar with the Gluon libraries, however. Another thing to check is that the `Icon` class is publicly available?